# ~/.bashrc not sourced in a new lxterminal window

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc

I added some lines to my ~/.bashrc like

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_22
```

I sourced it:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ env | grep 'JAVA'
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_22
```

Then I created a basic bash script under a folder called scripts in my home:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'start'
echo $(env | grep HOME)
echo $(env | grep LOGNAME)
echo $(env | grep JAVA)
echo 'exiting'

sleep 5
exit
```

Now, if I launch it directly I get the expected output

```
$ cd ~/scripts
$ bash 'myScript.sh'
start
HOME=/home/foo/.config
LOGNAME=foo
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_22
exiting
```

However I need to call it in a different way using the following command, and unluckily it doesn't work in the same way:

```
$ lxterminal --command "bash /home/foo/scripts/myScript.sh"
start
HOME=/home/foo XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/foo/.config
LOGNAME=foo

exiting
```

**It seems like .bashrc is not sourced in this way. I tried with .profile too, but with the same result.
Is there another file sourced by lxterminal when called with the above command?**

The reason why I need this command is because I want to launch these my own scripts through links/launchers I added to the start-menu and they have to be executed on a lxterminal window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try forcing `bash` to use interactive mode:

```
lxterminal --command "bash -i /home/foo/scripts/myScript.sh"
```

This happens because:

- `~/.bashrc` is read in interactive mode;
- `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` are read in login mode.

See **Invocation** in [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: Thanks for the tip: it worked like a charm. And thanks for the man part too ;) Sometimes it's hard to find something when you don't know exactly what to search ...